# Marionette + Handlebars without JS

Tags: java, grails, marionette, handlebars.js

It is possible to render my Marionette / Handlebars templates without JS using Java for older browsers?

Thanks

Comment: are you implying older browsers don't run JavaScript?

Comment: Mobile browser like Opera Mini or Android Browser < 4 causes a lot of troubles, maybe treat them like no js it's better

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. Both of these are JavaScript libraries.

It is possible to render handlebars templates server side using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You can try an isomorphic library for Backbone/Marionette, like https://github.com/gomoob/backbone.isomorphic but that will only run on nodeJS server.